Triviality of $\unicode{1064}(T_pE ⊗ T_pE)$ for elliptic curves and Bogomolov's lemma
Consider the case of an elliptic curve $E$ over Q, and let $S$ be a finite set of primes including all places of bad reduction and a place $p$ of good reduction.
Bogomolov's Lemma says that when $p$ is large enough, $$\unicode{1064}(T_pE):=\text{Ker}(H^1(G_S, T_pE)\longrightarrow H^1(G_p, T_pE))$$ is trivial.
This is also a corollary of the Fontaine Mazur conjecture for crystalline extensions of the trivial $G_S$ module $\mathbb{Q}_p$ by $T_pE$.
Similarly, the Fontaine-Mazur conjecture suggests that $\unicode{1064}(T_pE\otimes T_pE)$ is trivial. Is there any way to infer this triviality unconditionally for $p$ large enough, or after moving to a larger field? Alternatively, in case this should be easier, can we argue something to that effect for high enough tensor powers of $T_pE$?
